# Get IDs using Array SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I don't know how to create a Formula for It, but i have a table user. Schedule_ID (which are all array values). i want to get all IDs in schedule table that match the value in Schedule_ID.

it's like Where Schedule_ID(Any Value in Array(1,2,3)) = schedule.ID;

for now this is what i've got:

```
$sql="SELECT schedule.*,user.* FROM user
LEFT JOIN schedule ON user.Schedule_ID = schedule.ID
WHERE user.Schedule_ID = schedule.ID";
```

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter im using php and mysql

Comment: I left an answer for you let me know how if that solution worked for you.

Comment: @Jun what is your expectation and what undesirable output are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this query will do what you want:

```
SELECT schedule.*, user.* FROM user
LEFT JOIN schedule ON FIND_IN_SET(schedule.ID, user.Schedule_ID)
```

Note this query assumes the `Schedule_ID` field in `user` is of the form '1,2,3' or '6,8' etc.

Comment: Hi Nick, i tried your solution, it's not working.. There's already a Value for Schedule_ID which is (1,2,3) i need to Output schedule.ID which match the Schedule_ID. But thank you for answering

Comment: Does the value include the left and right brackets? i.e. it is a string `'(1,2,3)'`

Comment: Nope. i.e User 1 have Schedule_ID = 1,2,3. those 1,2,3 are Schedule.ID values in schedule table. Now i want to Output Schedules for User1 that match schedule.ID in user.Schedule_ID. So if there are many Schedules in schedule  table only those schedule.ID = 1,2,3 will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks! This solve the Problem. Thank you! It's working now

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator can help you out here, you may need to modify my answer depending on your setup but this should help you solve the problem or give you an idea.

```
SELECT schedule.ID
FROM schedule
LEFT JOIN schedule 
ON user.Schedule_ID = schedule.ID
WHERE schedule.ID IN (user.Schedule_ID)
```

Comment: hi @damian, i tried your solution but it's not working